# DialogflowApp askForUpdatePermission Not Working

Tags: permissions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

**1) askForUpdatePermission not finding intent**

I followed the Update Sample at [Github -dialogflow-updates-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs)  and got the update permission to work.

But when I added app.askForUpdatePermission("get.next.reminder") into my own code, the simulator says that my agent is not responding. I did not get the question to give update permission.

In the simulator error tab, I see an error:

```
MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found..
```

So I checked the intent name (get.next.reminder) again in my agent and it is clearly there and mapped to an action. I also tested that this intent can be triggered by user input.

The response tab shows the response like this:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\"]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
          "inputValueData": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
            "permissions": [
              "UPDATE"
            ],
            "updatePermissionValueSpec": {
              "intent": "get.next.reminder"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "d7edc1c1-1c67-49af-89bb-37e17ed35025"
    }
  }
}
```

Where I see `PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION` in the response text.

Not sure why it is not finding the intent.
Can anyone please please help with this?

---

**2) How to remove permissions?**

Also, a separate but related question: once you give the permission, how can you remove it? This is really important to be able to test.

Comment: I have the same problem. Followed the guide at https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications but it's no working

Comment: try to reset simulator and the version of simulator, it's worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

1) Is the "get.next.reminder" intent configured correctly?

Go to Google action console -> project -> overview -> 5:Action discovery and updates -> action "get.next.reminder" -> User updates and notifications -> Would you like to send push notifications?

Url should be: console.actions.google.com/project/your-project/overview/actionsdiscovery/action/get.next.reminder

2) To remove permission you must [clear your application](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#clear_the_content_of_the_userstorage) or click "turn off" in the notification

Comment: The user could remove permission from the notification itself https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/overview#manage_updates

Comment: Thank you @user. I figured out that Action Discovery piece was missing.

Comment: For Removing Permissions, is there a way to do this programmatically via API?

Comment: Unable to find Action discovery and updates. Please help

Comment: I am also took for Action Discovery and updates and haven't located it yet.

Answer (score 0):

To stop receiving updates, you can also take the following steps:

1. Exit your app. Saying "Exit" will always exit the app.
2. Say "Stop sending updates from [APP_NAME]"

Google Assistant will say "Are you sure you want to stop receiving updates from [APP_NAME]?"

Say yes.