# Dialogflow push notification permissions not working on real device but perfectly fine on simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am following google's tutorial on push notification. 
It is working perfectly on the simulator.

This function which works on the simulator:

```
const setupPushNotification = (conv) => {
    conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({
        intent: "newSales"
    }));
}
```

returns this error when called from a real device :

```
Not allowed to ask for permission to send updates for an intent that does not have push updates enabled
```

I tried to disable/enable again push updates but i am still getting the same error when using it on my phone.

The intent is clearly found as i am not getting this error:

```
The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found.
```

Any ideas, is there something else to enable to make push notification permission work on my smartphone ?
Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DialogflowApp askForUpdatePermission Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661752/dialogflowapp-askforupdatepermission-not-working)